# Mi ordenamiento burbuja no funciona correctamente, Lista doblemente ligada

Tags: c++, lista, c++11, ordenamiento

Como actividad tengo que usar una lista doblemente ligada creada por mi, y de igual manera implementar un método burbuja para ordenar los valores.

Mi Nodo es el siguiente:

```
template<class T>
class NodoD{
    private:
        T dato;
        NodoD<T> *sig;
        NodoD<T> *ant;
    public:
        NodoD(const T &d){
            dato = d;
            sig = nullptr;
            ant = nullptr;
        }
        template <class> friend class ListaDoble;
    };
```

El método burbuja de la lista es:

```
template <class T>
void ListaDoble<T>::bubbleSort()
{
    NodoD<T> *current = primero;
    T dummy;

    if (current == NULL) return;
    if (current->sig == NULL) return;

    int swapped = 1;
    while (swapped){
        current = primero;
         //last pass unless there is a swap
        swapped = 0;
        while (current->sig != NULL){
            //swapped ++;
            if (current->dato > current->sig->dato){
                swapped = 1; //swap, will need to re-enter while loop
                //actual number swap
                dummy = current->dato;
                current->dato = current->sig->dato;
                current->sig->dato = dummy;
            }
            current = current->sig;
        }
        if (swapped)
            current = primero;
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero ordenar son unos char*, la clase es la siguiente:

```
long int direccion;
char rfcProfe[13];
char estado[2];
```

Dado que son char, sobrecargue los operadores para poder comparar, convirtiendo todo el char a un entero:

```
bool Indice::operator ==(const Indice &i)
{
    int rfc = std::atoi(rfcProfe);
    int _rfc = std::atoi(i.rfcProfe);
    return rfc == _rfc;
}

bool Indice::operator !=(const Indice &i)
{
    int rfc = std::atoi(rfcProfe);
    int _rfc = std::atoi(i.rfcProfe);
    return rfc != _rfc;
}

bool Indice::operator <=(const Indice &i)
{
    int rfc = std::atoi(rfcProfe);
    int _rfc = std::atoi(i.rfcProfe);
    return rfc <= _rfc;
}

bool Indice::operator >=(const Indice &i)
{
    int rfc = std::atoi(rfcProfe);
    int _rfc = std::atoi(i.rfcProfe);
    return rfc >= _rfc;
}

bool Indice::operator <(const Indice &i)
{
    int rfc = std::atoi(rfcProfe);
    int _rfc = std::atoi(i.rfcProfe);
    return rfc < _rfc;
}

bool Indice::operator >(const Indice &i)
{
    int rfc = std::atoi(rfcProfe);
    int _rfc = std::atoi(i.rfcProfe);
    return rfc > _rfc;
}
```

Los datos ingresados son los siguientes:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjXKw.png

[image: Imagen Datos ingresados]

Y los datos que obtengo al hacer el ordenamiento, son los siguientes:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuh1b.png

[image: Datos obtenidos]

EDIT: Use quicksort en mis lista, y de la misma manera el burbuja pero hay un elemento que no se ordena.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/poHs5.png
[image: No se ordena]

Comment: ¿Puedes incluir la definición de `Indice`? Me interesa echar un vistazo a los constructores y operadores de copia.

Comment: si mal no recuerdo cuando comparas caracteres a > b es false asi q no veo la necesidad de sobrecargar los operadores.

Comment: No tengo operados o constructores copia en mi Indice, al momento de guardar el profesor, guardo de igual manera el indice, básicamente copio los datos que el usuario ingresa en el objeto Profesor, al objeto Indice, @Paula_plus_plus

Comment: Sobrecargo los operadores para evaluar específicamente el "rfc" del objeto, @AlexRivas